# Facebook like SDK does not work on first load

Tags: javascript, facebook

My goal is to alert message after user likes Facebook page by using Facebook like button on webpage. I saw several questions regarding how to do it here on Stack overflow. This is my solution.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/something" data-width="" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-share="false"></div>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
      
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
        alert('I just clicked like button');
    });
    // Code to detect clicking unlike
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(href) {
        alert('Unlike');
    });
};
       

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if(d.getElementById(id)){return;}
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=116903184989287";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

      </script>
```

My problem is that on first load window.fbAsyncInit does not preform at all, the page is liked, but no alert message. After refresh it starts working, but even then it takes time to show the message (a bit slow).
I am new to Facebook SDK and any help is welcome.
Regards

P.S. I am testing on localhost